# SQL Server maintenance plan not working after renaming administrator

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plans, windows-server

I have renamed the Windows administrator account to `TEST` using Local Group Policy editor. After that, the SQL Server maintenance plans are not working anymore:

> Unable to determine if the owner of job has server access

I have tried methods below but no luck yet:

1. I have tried to add a login to SQL Server for `TEST` account, but it says that this login already exists. I can not see the name of `TEST` in the `Login` tab, but the administrator exists already
2. I have deleted the Maintenance plans and created new ones but no change happened

Please let me know if there is another way to connect the Maintenance plans to the new administrator name.

Comment: Have a look at Ms Docs about how to configure services accounts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Let me suggest to create isolated accounts for SQL services.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to rename the built in administrator account in the LOGINs of Sql server? @McNets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

1. Expanding Server --> security
2. Expanding Logins
3. Right click on administrator account and simply rename it to the new name (I had renamed before only in Local Group Policy).
4. Maintenance plans works fine!